# Getting an error for no reason I can comprehend

Tags: objective-c, malloc

I clicked equals, and it runs all the code and reaches the end at clear, runs that and gets to the end and NSLogs it.  At this point it has nothing more to do.... expect give me an error message for no reason, any idea why?
Thanks!

```
-(IBAction) clickEquals: (id) sender {
    // more stuff is actually insider here, omitted for brevity.
    [self clear];
}

- (void)clear {
    // more stuff is actually insider here, omitted for brevity.
    [accumulator clear];
    NSLog(@"clear - done");
}
```

Console

> 2010-12-29 15:24:38.328
>   app[6150:207] clear - done
>
> app(6150,0xa01e7540) malloc: * * * error
>   for object 0x7146840: pointer being
>   freed was not allocated
>   * * * set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> (gdb)

Comment: It’s hard to tell from the code snippets you’ve pasted. You’re likely to get accurate answers if you’re able to provide a minimal test case that reproduces the error.

Comment: Do you know what the error message means at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app(6150,0xa01e7540) malloc: * * *
>   error for object 0x7146840: pointer
>   being freed was not allocated * * *
>   set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break
>   to debug

Your program has caused something to be freed that was never allocated.  More likely than not, it is because a garbage pointer was passed to `free()`, maybe because you forgot to initialize something or maybe because your app is trashing memory.

In any case, follow the instructions and set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` and post the backtrace.

More likely than not, the cause is in the *// more stuff is actually insider here, omitted for brevity.* bits or in the `[accumulator clear]` method.

Comment: Thank you! Found the error, I was autoreleasing a object that I never allocated space for.  For future reference: Where would I go about putting a breakpoint? I don't recognize malloc_error_break.

Comment: You would add a symbolic breakpoint;  either in the breakpoint window of Xcode or by typing `b malloc_error_break` in the GDB terminal window.